# Make Bootstrap's YAMM open on hover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, megamenu

I'm using the YAMM to create a mega menu for Bootstrap but I can't figure out how to make the menu appear on mouseover/hover. At the moment it only appears on click.

[github demo](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vYr2/)

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar yamm">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav1">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="brand" href="#"> Yamm Megamenu </a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse" id="nav1">
          <ul class="nav">
            <!-- Classic list -->
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> List <b class="caret"></b> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <!-- Content container to add padding -->
                  <div class="yamm-content">
                    <ul class="span2 unstyled">
                      <li><p><strong>Section Title</strong></p></li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="span2 unstyled">
                      <li><p><strong>Links Title</strong></p></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="span2 unstyled">
                      <li><p><strong>Section Title</strong></p></li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="span2 unstyled">
                      <li><p><strong>Section Title</strong></p></li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        List Item
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#"> Link Item </a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Accordion demo -->
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Accordion <b class="caret"></b> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="yamm-content">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <div id="accordion2" class="accordion  span6">
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                          <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle collapsed"> Collapsible Group Item #1 </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseOne" style="height: 0px;">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                              Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                          <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle"> Collapsible Group Item #2 </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseTwo">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                              Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                          <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapseThree" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle"> Collapsible Group Item #3 </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseThree">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                              Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div id="accordion3" class="accordion  span6">
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                          <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapseOne1" data-parent="#accordion3" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle collapsed"> Collapsible Group Item #1 </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseOne1" style="height: 0px;">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                              Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                          <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapseTwo1" data-parent="#accordion3" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle"> Collapsible Group Item #2 </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseTwo1">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                              Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                          <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapseThree1" data-parent="#accordion3" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle"> Collapsible Group Item #3 </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseThree1">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                              Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Classic dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Classic <b class="caret"></b> </a><!-- Classic Dropdown -->
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Action </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Another action </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Something else here </a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Separated link </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Pictures -->
            <li class="dropdown yamm-fullwidth">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Pictures <b class="caret"></b> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="yamm-content">
                    <!-- thumbnails needs a row-fluid to make span fluid -->
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img alt="150x190" data-src="holder.js/150x90"> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img alt="150x190" data-src="holder.js/150x90"> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img alt="150x190" data-src="holder.js/150x90"> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img alt="150x190" data-src="holder.js/150x90"> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img alt="150x190" data-src="holder.js/150x90"> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img alt="150x190" data-src="holder.js/150x90"> </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make `display: block` when the particular `li` is hoverd.

Add this in your css code

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: this causes the dropdown links to shift, not advised

Comment: What dropdown link, I think you're refering to the main header item shifts on hover, but that too shifts on click also

Comment: you are right my bad. But that leads me to believe there is another error in the markup. but your answer is correct

Comment: Hmm, that can be solved by adding some `width` in the `li` item.

Comment: Yes, this CSS solution works on hover. However, if you click on a dropdown-toggle, it remains open, and then if you hover on something else, there will be 2 overlayed dropdown-menus. It is not very obvious however, there's just a change in shadow, but it does become obvious when you style the open dropdown-toggle.

Comment: amazing. i was expecting a jquery answer

Comment: this is worked but class name if dropdown worked if any other class name you must rename and edit this line of code ul.navName li.dropdownClassName

Answer (score 1):

A lot of plugins available for show bootstrap dropdown on hover. Here i have used one plugin for demo refer the following url

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/azhagu/6vYr2/2/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* disable dropping down on mouse click */
    ul.nav li.open > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: none;    
    }
    /* enable dropping down on mouse hover */
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;    
    }
}
```